# Display a customer's total order number

Tags: woocommerce

How do I display a customer's total order number on the woocommerce my account page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_before_account_orders` hook to display the number of orders.

```php
function bks_action_woocommerce_before_account_orders( $has_orders ) {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ), // Feel free to change the post_status to the once you want.
    ) );

    $total_orders = count($customer_orders);
    
    // If customer has any orders then only show total number of orders.
    if ( $has_orders ) {
        echo 'No. of order : ' . $total_orders;
    }

};
    
    // add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', 'bks_action_woocommerce_before_account_orders', 10, 1 );
```

Don't add this code in `functions.php`. Use a custom plugin so that your customizations aren't lost during updates. Use this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Tested and WORKS.
[image: Order page screenshot]

Comment: The code works. So why use the plugin for this?

Comment: Because if you add this code in your theme file and update your theme this code get lost. If you are using a child theme you can, add this code there as well. Just don't add it in the theme file. Read this article by woocommerce itself. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customizing-woocommerce-best-practices
If this answer is working for you and you are satisfied with it, consider marking it as the correct answer. The plugin is for you to add the code in safe manner, it isn't required for the functionality. It just helps you to add custom codes inside wordpress.  @MaryXNabors