# How do I add how many orders the customer has placed before on the woocommerce orders page?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to add one more column to the order list. I want to print the number of orders for that customer so far in the column I will add.

Comment: You can copy orders.php template from woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php and add it in your theme - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ . After that you can count $customer_orders like this - $total = count($customer_orders->orders;

Comment: another way is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797526/display-a-customers-total-order-number

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thank you for your return. I want to add the total number of orders of the customer to the list of orders when I log in to the Admin. That is, not to the customer's own account page.